# How to copy multiple lines one under each line separately?

Tags: vim

Sorry for the bad english, see this example:

original

```
a
line01
line02
line03
line04
b
```

want to become:

```
a
line01
line01
line02
line02
line03
line03
line04
line04
b
```

`a` and `b` are irrelevant.

I can copy one line and paste, and repeat. Is there any simple solution? like one command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a global command, this could easily be done like this

```
:g/^/t.
```

**Breakdown**

```
:g              start a global command
/^              search for a begin of line (every line matches)
/t.             copy the current line
```

Comment: Or you can select current paragraph with `vip` (visual select inner paragraph) and when you type `:` vim will show `:'<,'>` so you already have your range selected, finally `:'<,'>g/^/t.`

Comment: @SergioAraujo always come across `:'<,'>`, does not know what it means, thanks. anyway, where should I put the cursor on? I put the cursor on `line01` and type `vip`, the whole paragraph is selected, how to select only `line01` to `line04` and ignore the line `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Sato - with your cursor on `line01` and after starting a selection, you could use `/^b/-1` or `/line04` to expand the visual selection up until `line04`.

Comment: After 'vip' press 'ojok' to change the limits of your selection

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a vim macro-

With your cursor at line 0, column 0; record a macro, store in register `a`

```
qa
```

Copy the current line; paste it below; move your cursor down to the next line

```
yypj
```

Save the Macro

```
q
```

Now run the `a` macro N number of times (it will stop at the bottom of the file regardless)

```
3@q
```

Answer (score 0):

For funsies a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed 'p' input.txt > output.txt
```

Using filter, `:!`, inside of Vim:

```
:%!sed p
```

Obligatory awk solution: `awk '1;1' input.txt > output.txt`.